# Creating a simple stored procedure reaching max execution time

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a simple stored procedure in phpmyadmin.

But the page is taking for long time and reaches the maximum execution time which results in an error.

This is the table structure:

```
id  usr_id  message
1   1   dfsfa
2   2   fd
3   1   fsdfsdf
4   1   fsd
5   1   fsdvxc
```

This is the store procedure query I am trying to execute:

```
delimiter //
    create procedure myProc()
    begin
      select message from consecutive;
    end //
    delimiter ;
```

This is the error I am getting:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in
>   D:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\libraries\import\sql.php on line 119

Comment: How are you calling the stored procedure?

Comment: i am executing it directly in phpmyadmin. It is not even creating.

Comment: Oh, so you are trying to set it up, and not actually call it then?

Comment: Yes i am trying to set up only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `myProc`()
BEGIN
    select message from consecutive;
END
```

Comment: I actually just used this in my own phpMyAdmin, and it worked fine.

Comment: Ya. it is working. Thanks  and can you please suggest me some site or books where i can learn from very basic.

Comment: @Udhay Really, all the ones I seen show examples exactly like the one in your original code.  So I'm really not sure what to point you to.  Though, I think they are all correct, and that it's actually phpMyAdmin just not liking the delimiters.  But here's one that I hope helps.  Maybe just ignore the delimiter parts and just use the one in my example since you know it works for you.  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If that is your entire stored procedure then the reason is as simple as you're not doing anything. If we go through the thing line by line:

Create the procedure

```
create procedure myProc()
```

Indicate the start of code

```
begin
```

Select **every row** from `consecutive`

```
select message from consecutive;
```

The end

```
end
```

As you can see you're not actually doing anything other than selecting everything from a single table, which is why it's taking so long.

It would be normal if your query was something like:

```
select message 
  from consecutive
 where id = my_passed_variable

 -- do something else...
```

Comment: Since i am new to stored procedure can you please suggest me some site or books where i can learn from very basic.

Comment: He's actually just trying to set up the stored procedure, and not call it.